# How to plug module in controller only in production env?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

How to plug module in controller only in production env?

Example:

```
plug BasicAuth, realm: "Admin Area", username: "admin", password: "pass"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take advantage of `Mix`'s environments. You can selectively add the `plug` call only in the production environment with something like this:

```
if Mix.env == :prod do
  plug BasicAuth, realm: "Admin Area", username: "admin", password: "pass"
end
```

This line will not compile to anything (`nil`) if the `Mix.env` is not production.

Comment: great example! exactly what i was looking for. your answer raises a great question... how did you know BasicAuth can take params like `realm:`, `username:` etc... ? it is not in the docs!

Answer (score 8):

While @whatyouhide's answer is correct, be careful using `Mix.env` in your project outside of mix tasks.  If you decide to use Exrm or relx to build OTP releases, the mix library will not be included and this will crash your app on startup.

As an alternative, you can add an `:env` key to each environment's respective config file with the env value in it and then use it much like you would `Mix.env`.

Comment: To expand on this a little, you could even use a key that is specific to the feature and not the environment. For example having a `:admin_auth` key with a `true` or `false` value. That way, the functionality is not tied to your environment making it easier to enable the feature in development to ensure it works.

Comment: @Gazler's suggestion is great.  Being more explicit will never come back to bite you.  However, being less explicit can.